# ko.subscribe on child model properties

Tags: javascript, data-binding, mvvm, viewmodel, knockout.js

Looking for a good example of how to set up child models in knockoutjs. This includes binding to child events such as property updates which I haven't been able to get working yet.

Also, it would be better to bind to a single child in this case instead of an array but I don't know how to set it up in the html without the foreach template.

http://jsfiddle.net/mathewvance/mfYNq/

Thanks.

```html
<div class="editor-row">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input name="Price" data-bind="value: price"/>
</div>

 <div class="editor-row">
    <label>Child</label>
    <div data-bind="foreach: childObjects"> 
        <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: yearRound" /> Year Round</div>
        <div><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: fromNow" /> From Now</div>
        <div>
            <input data-bind="value: startDate" class="date-picker"/> to 
            <input data-bind="value: endDate" class="date-picker"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
var ChildModel= function (yearRound, fromNow, startDate, endDate) {
    var self = this;

    this.yearRound = ko.observable(yearRound);
    this.fromNow = ko.observable(fromNow);
    this.startDate = ko.observable(startDate);
    this.endDate = ko.observable(endDate);

    this.yearRound.subscribe = function (val) {
        alert('message from child model property subscribe\n\nwhy does this only happen once?');

        //if(val){
        //    self.startDate('undefined');
        //    self.endDate('undefined');
        //}
    };
}

var ParentModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    this.price = ko.observable(1.99);
    this.childObjects = ko.observableArray([ new ChildModel(true, false) ]);
};

var viewModel = new ParentModel ();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

Comment: If You want single child instead of array and don't want to repeat yourself with parent levels, then use `with` binding [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AlfeG/xn6rg/)

Comment: Thanks for this. I hadn't come across an example using the single with binding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it with the following:

```js
this.yearRound.subscribe(function (val) {
        alert('value change');
    });
```

If you want to have the subscriber also being called while loading the page do something like this:

```js
var ChildModel= function (yearRound, fromNow, startDate, endDate) {
    var self = this;

    this.yearRound = ko.observable();
    this.fromNow = ko.observable(fromNow);
    this.startDate = ko.observable(startDate);
    this.endDate = ko.observable(endDate);

    this.yearRound.subscribe(function (val) {
        alert('value change');
    });
    this.yearRound(yearRound);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/azQxx/1/ - this works for me with Chrome 16 and Firefox 10

Every time the checked button changes its value the callback fires.

The `observableArray` is fine in my opinion if you may have more than one child model associated to the parent.

Comment: I tested this and expected the alert to be fired each time the check box state was changed. Nothing happened though.

Comment: I added a jsfiddle reference. The jsfiddle works for me for firefox 10 and chrome 16

Comment: This example works because fyr is not assigning the subscribe variable.  He's executing the subscribe function with a nested function.  `yearRound.subscribe(function(){})` is different from `yearRound.subscribe = function(){}`

Comment: Thanks soniiic, I did miss that distinction. And thank you for an answer fyr, it's testing great now.